# Convert Timestamp in numerical format to LocalDateTime in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format

On an API call, I am receiving timestamp as: 1591290491238. I need to convert it to LocalDateTime in Java. I have written the code as:

```
String timestamp = "1584453053825";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdduuHHmmss");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( timestamp , formatter );
```

But it is **throwing** an **error**:

```
Text '1584453053825' could not be parsed at index 12
```

Comment: FYI, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type here. Your input number likely represents a count since epoch reference. As such, that input represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. For that you need the `Instant` class. The `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Comment: @BasilBourque is very right, don’t use `LocalDateTime` here (and seldom use it at all). If you want date and time of day, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: What did your search bring up? Mine found this, I think it’s helpful: [Java - How to convert epoch milliseconds to LocalDateTime?](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java-8-date-time-api/millis-to-date.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number represents time in Unix format, that is the number of milliseconds elapsed since the epoch, which is January 1st, 1970 at midnight UTC.

You can convert it to `LocalDateTime` like this:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(timestamp)), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use ZonedDateTime for date and time of day

Your timestamp is a count of milliseconds since the Java/Unix epoch of January 1, 1970 at the start of day in UTC. To convert it to a date and time of day you first need to decide on a time zone for that since it is never the same time (not even the same date) in all time zones. As long as the count is greater than 1000, Java parses a string containing it directly.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    DateTimeFormatter numericalFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS, 1, 19, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
            .toFormatter()
            .withZone(zone);
    
    String timestamp = "1591290491238";
    
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp, numericalFormatter);
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from this example snippet is:

> 2020-06-04T13:08:11.238-04:00[America/New_York]

As Basil Bourque already said in a comment, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for your date and time. `ZonedDateTime` gives you the same and more since it also holds the time zone and therefore defines the point in time that the original timestamp string defined. You may convert to `LocalDateTime` thereby throwing away information that you want to keep. So only do it if you need a `LocalDateTime` for an API designed by people who didn’t understand that this was the wrong class.

```
    LocalDateTime amputatedDateTime = dateTime.toLocalDateTime();
    System.out.println(amputatedDateTime);
```

> 2020-06-04T13:08:11.238

You notice that we have now lost the offset from UTC and the time zone.

### What went wrong in your code?

You tried to parse the string using a format pattern of `MMdduuHHmmss`. The pattern defines 12 digits, but there are 13 in the string. The pattern you used would assume that 1591290491238 refers to day 12 of month 159 of year 2090 at 49:12:38 on a 24 hours clock, or something like that. It’s nonsense. Also because, as I said, the number refers to a point in time, not to a date and time, and to obtain the latter, we first need to supply a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp is actually the number of milliseconds from the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` where `Z` stands for `Zulu` date-time or date-time in UTC (i.e. at a timezone offset of `+00:00` hours). You should parse it to a `long` and then get the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from it.

Once you have an object of `Instant`, you can get objects of other date-time types from it as shown below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timestamp = "1584453053825";
        long epochMilli = Long.parseLong(timestamp);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli);

        // Convert instant to ZonedDateTime with the time zone of JVM
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        // Get LocalDateTime from instant
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();

        // Display ldt in the default format i.e. the value returned by ldt#toString
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Display ldt in a custom format e.g. EEE MMMM dd, uuuu hh:mm:ss a
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMMM dd, uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-03-17T13:50:53.825
Tue March 17, 2020 01:50:53 PM
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.