# Java how to Format Date to yyyy-MM-dd?

Tags: java, date, formatting

Hey there I have a question regarding the way that Java parses or formatts a Date.

I have this code:

```
private DateFormat dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.GERMAN);
private DateFormat dateFormatter2 = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.GERMAN);
```

...

```
        String dateTest = dateFormatter.format(Long.parseLong(pair.getKey().get(3)));
        String dateTest2 = dateFormatter2.format(Long.parseLong(pair.getKey().get(3)));

            System.out.println("dateTest: " + dateTest + " || dateTest2: " + dateTest2);
```

This gives me following result:

```
dateTest: Donnerstag, 2. Februar 2023 || dateTest2: 02.02.2023
```

Now I want to convert the date to this Format: "yyyy-MM-dd". I tried with simpledateformatter and the Parse function but always ended up in Errors like this:

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02.02.2023"
```

How can I simply change the date to my desired format? Would be cool if the result was of type Date.

DateFormatter only shows me how to do it from a Date but I have a String. The Problem is that I dont know how to change the String into a Date.

`new Date(string)` and `(Date) string` do not work.

Edit:

```
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateTest2, formatter);
            System.out.println("NewDate " + date);
```

result is:

```
SEVERE: Uncaught Exception
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01.02.2023' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-datetimeformatter

Comment: The thing is that it only tell me how to format a date in the dateformatter but I have a string. Could you tell me how to format that string to a date first? new Date(string) or (Date) string do not work.

Comment: You don't *format* a string to a date - you *parse* a string to a date. Hopefully that clue will help you in your research. But I'd *strongly* recommend that you use java.time instead. And given that it looks like your data *actually* starts with a `long` value, not a string, it sounds like you don't really need to do that anyway... If you find yourself formatting a value and then parsing the result, try to find a way of going straight from the original value to the desired result *without* string conversions.

Comment: @JonSkeet well honestly I dont get it.. I tried to parse the date again but it just does not work :/ Edited my Question maybe someone knows whats going on.

Comment: Since I understand from your code that `pair.getKey().get(3)` returns a *`String`*, I suggest looking at these similar questions: [Convert Timestamp in numerical format to LocalDateTime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199689/convert-timestamp-in-numerical-format-to-localdatetime-in-java) and [Trying to create a timestamp "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" for a chat for android using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445645/trying-to-create-a-timestamp-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-a-for-a-chat-for-android-using-j).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need something like:

```
LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(pair.getKey().get(3))).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(date);
```

If you have to have `Date`, you can do:

```
Date d = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(pair.getKey().get(3))));
```

Comment: Jesus Christ that actually works :D Thanks man I have no Idea how someone actually is able to know that this is the way to format in my case. Thanks. One more thing tho: this is a localdate how would you change it to a "normal" Date?

Comment: Ok I found a Function to convert it from LocalDate to Date.

Comment: No - that's the wrong way around. You should be using the new date/time api as I showed. Why do you think you need `Date`?

Comment: Because I have functions that need the variable to be Date not LocalDate.

Comment: That's a shame. But there's a further issue in that case. Presumably, you're aware that `Date` contains *time* info? Is that time info actually *used*?

Comment: Mh yeah I see that beacuse actually I am getting this back: Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 CET 2023 so its not even the format I wanted but as it is a date it gets handled correctly by my following functions and calls. As of now everything works as expected for me ^^

Comment: Good. Keep an eye on that and see my edit above

Comment: Yeah thanks ended up using your Edit because it is shorter - ty.

Comment: `Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMillis(x))` is still a very long-winded way of writing `new Date(x)` - see my answer, now that it's clearer that what's desired (a java.util.Date from a long) has nothing to do with text representations.

Answer (score 3):

If you *just* need to get a `java.util.Date` from a `long` value which is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, it really is trivial:

```java
long millis = Long.parseLong(pair.getKey().get(3));
Date date = new Date(millis);
```

Or inlined if you really want to:

```java
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(pair.getKey().get(3)));
```

I would *strongly* advise you to try to migrate all your code to `java.time` though. It's a *far* superior API.